# Matlab : Open previously saved figures and save as

Tags: matlab, plot, printing, save

I'm writing a Matlab code which plots and saves figures as png and eps.

```
h = figure(3);
    plot(x,y)
    xlabel('x'); ylabel('y');

        FileName = sprintf('FileName.eps');
        print(h,'-depsc', '-loose', FileName);

        FileName = sprintf('FileName.png);
        print(clhis,'-dpng', '-loose', FileName);

close(h)
```

I would like to just save them as FileName.fig for later process.
The function/script I would like to create would read all *.fig in current dir and save them as defined function.

Here is a pseudo function... But I'm not sure how to make it work properly!

```
function figureconvert(ext)    % NOT WORKING! Just a mock up!
ext = 'eps';        

Vector = READ ALL FIGS IN FOLDER;

for i = 1:length(Vector)
h = load Vector(i)

            FileName = sprintf('FileName.%s',ext);
            % print(h,'-d%sc', '-loose', FileName); ??

    close(h)
end
end
```

Comment: Before closing it do `savefig(h,'myname.fig')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution how to do this. Here is my function if someone else will need such function.

Just write:

```
 figureconvert('png')   or     figureconvert('eps')
```

to convert *.fig to *.png or *.eps respectively.

```
function figureconvert(ext)
Files = dir('*.fig');
ext = ['.',ext]; ext = strrep(ext,'..','.');

for i = 1:length(Files)
    figname = Files(i,1).name;
    h = openfig(figname);
    FigName = strrep(figname,'.fig',ext);

    if strcmp(ext,'.eps')
        print(h,'-depsc', '-loose', FigName);
    elseif strcmp(ext,'.png')
        print(h,'-dpng', '-loose', FigName);
    end

    close(h)
end
end
```